# How to fail on save operation if the object already exists in DB with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to save an object into DB with JPA. Object has two property age and email. Email is @Id and of type String.

If I attempt to save two objects with same email. the last one makes an update on to the DB.

How do I make the last save fail ?

```
class Person {


    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;
    private int age;

}
```

Comment: Can you show the way you are trying to save?

Comment: Don't use *email* field as Identifier but instead add additional autoincrement id  column for system use and then put a unique constraint on email.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going is not recommended.

You could have Person class something like below and validate email before only.

```
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(unique=true) 
    private String email;

    private int age;
}
```